# Flywheel in a motorcycle

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Flywheel is used to store energy for the non power producing strokes of an IC(internal combustion) engine,  do we use a fly wheel in an motorcycle and if yes what is it's size and where is it placed?

Comment: I assume that you were doing theory of machines because while I was studying Theory of machines I had same doubt.

Answer (score 2):

```
do we use a fly wheel in an motorcycle
```

Yes we do.

to store the energy generated in the power stroke which is supplied that energy to other strokes and the traction effort of motorcycle

```
where is it placed?
```

The location of flywheel is directly next to the engine shaft (crack shaft)directly next to flywheel is a clutch with a spring arrangements and a diaphragm clutch (its motorcycle). The following image will give you an idea how that arrangement is.

[image]

EDIT:

**Here is an illustrative image of the ECG (engine clutch gearbox)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as on any IC engine — the flywheel is mounted directly on the crankshaft. Why would it be anywhere else?

YouTube: [HOW TO REMOVE A MOTORCYCLE FLYWHEEL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgU2mtZ2axM)